# Powershell Invoke-Command query

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm scripting a task to remotely restart some server application pools periodically. I'm using Invoke-Command as follows:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {Restart-WebItem "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool"}
```

and this works just fine; however, if I parameterize the app pool as follows

```
$appPool = "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {Restart-WebItem $appPool}
```

it fails with

```
Unexpected object type.
Parameter name: pspath
```

I assume this is just a syntax issue, but I can't work out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the remote host $appPool will not exist.
If you're using PS V3 you can prefix your variable with `using:` keyword ->

```
$appPool = "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {Restart-WebItem $using:appPool}
```

prior to version 3, you had to use the `-argumentList` parameter

Comment: Excellent the $using syntax worked. Strangely I was under the impression that the local variable was resolved prior to the command being remotely executed. 
I was getting the same error message using -ArgumentList.

Comment: @KevinRoche nope, this is why `-argumentlist` is made for : "Supplies the values of local variables in the command. The variables in the command are replaced by these values before the command is run on the remote computer."

Comment: Just tried a few tests with -ArgumentList but I'm missing something. The -PSPath parameter for this function is a string array so I tried {Restart-WebItem} -ArgumentList (,$appPool) and also {Restart-WebItem} -ArgumentList $appPool - same error as original. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: staight from the doc: To use local variables in a command, use the following command format:
`{param($<name1>[, $<name2>]...) <command-with-local-variables>} -ArgumentList <value> -or- <local-variable>`